# Write from custom start of file to custom number of bytes

Tags: java, buffer

How to read from a input stream with an offset and write a certain number of bytes to an output stream?

The goal is to, for example, skip 512 bytes from an `InputStream` and write 1024 byte, with the 512 byte offset, to an `OutputStream`, but also be buffered if the buffer itself is defined as `4096` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Use a technique called adaptive buffer. For example, first define a array of bytes to store data in, and the desired buffer size:

```
private static final int FS_BUFFER = 4096;
private byte[] buff = new byte[FS_BUFFER];
```

Then use this code, which i will explain now:

```
int size = 1024; // the desired length of bytes
raf.seek(512); // the desired input file offset

RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile( /* File here */ , "r");
BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream( /* output stream here */);

int maxBuf = FS_BUFFER > size ? size : FS_BUFFER;

for (int b, written = 0, left; (b = raf.read(buff, 0, maxBuf)) > 0; ) {

    written += b;
    left = size - written;

    maxBuf = left < FS_BUFFER ? left : FS_BUFFER;
    bufferedOutputStream.write(buff, 0, b);

}
```

Lets break the code down:

```
int maxBuf = FS_BUFFER > size ? size : FS_BUFFER;
```

Here we first check if the actual size to write is smaller than the buffer itself. If it is, set the maximum number of bytes to read from the `RandomAccessFile` to the file size, so the file gets read from disk in one pass.

If the desired number of bytes is bigger than the buffer, just use the buffer size as the maximum number of bytes to read.

```
for (int b, written = 0, left; (b = raf.read(buff, 0, maxBuf)) > 0; )
```

Here, define the integers for bytes, the amount of data written, and the amount of data left to write. Then, read from the `RandomAccessFile` and store bytes in buffer, with the maximum number of bytes to read at a time being `maxBuf`, which we defined based on the file size and buffer size.

```
written += b;
left = size - written;
```

Here we calculate the amount of bytes we will write, and the amount of bytes left to read after the pass.

```
maxBuf = left < FS_BUFFER ? left : FS_BUFFER;
```

Here we now check, if the number of bytes left to read is smaller than the buffer, if it is, we set the maximum number of bytes to be read for the next pass to the amount of bytes left to read.

```
bufferedOutputStream.write(buff, 0, b);
```

And here we perform the actual writing to the `OutputStream`.

So, what this code will do, is read from an RandomAccessFile to an `*OutputStream` a certain number of bytes, and adapt the buffer to either the amount left to write, file size itself it the amount of data is smaller than the buffer, or the preset buffer. This results in an constant buffered stream of data between the two `*Streams`